# Build prod don’t display font - basic webpack init

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, fonts, production

I need to use font named ‘myFontName’ from ttf file in production environment after launch this command :

```
npm run build
```

For this test, i have only initialize project with this command :

```
vue init webpack myProjectName
```

In dev environment (npm run dev) i can display and use my font. But i can’t see the same font after build. However, in the production environment i can see my font in css rules (browser console).

> So, font seems to be display in dev and not in production.

This is my tree project:

```
src
|_assets
|_components
   |componentfile.vue
   |_fonts
      |_myFontFile.ttf
```

This is my dist folder tree :

```
dist
|_js
|_static
   |_fonts
      |_myFontFile.ttf
```

I call my font directly in my component.vue file :

```
<script scoped>
@font-face{
font-family:"myFontName";
src: url("./fonts/myFontFile.ttf") format("truetype");
}
<script>
```

Webpack is nativ from init. I have this loader in my webpack.base.conf.js :

```
{
test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
loader: 'url-loader',
options: {
  limit: 10000,
  name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
 }
}
```

For build config :

```
build{
  build.assetsPublicPath: ‘/’
}
```

So, what's wrong ? Why prod env don't display my font correctly ?
Thanks to help me to resolve this font problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay no response ? Nobody...

Finally, here is my solution.

In util.js file, insert :

```
publicPath: '../../'
```

In this part of code

```
// Extract CSS when that option is specified
// (which is the case during production build)
if (options.extract) {
  return ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: loaders,
    fallback: 'vue-style-loader',
    publicPath: '../../'
  })
} else {
  return ['vue-style-loader'].concat(loaders)
}
```

But why ?

> Check this two similar issues..
>
> [Vuejs forum similar issue](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/build-prod-dont-display-font-)
>   [Github similar issue](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/166)

After build, i can inspect style CSS files in

```
/dist/src/static/css/
```

... and noted that my @font-face source have the wrong path after build according to ma dist tree folder :

```
@font-face{font-family:myFontFileBis;src:url(static/fonts/myFontFileBis.ttf) format("truetype")}
```

Instead of **url(static/fonts/myFontFileBis.ttf)**, i need to get **url(../../static/fonts/myFontFileBis.ttf)**.

So, i need to set publicPath in util.js.

it work now !